# Microsoft Fakes (Shims and / or Stubs) on a c# method with SQL code

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, shim, microsoft-fakes, stubs

I am trying to learn a bit more about Unit Testing, using out-of-the-box functionality (i believe it is MSTest.exe), and Microsoft Fakes (stubs and Shims).

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and .Net 4.5 Framework.

Given the following code that calls a stored procedure (SQL Server) which returns a single output value (for simplicity):

```
public string GetSomeDatabaseValue()
{
    string someValue = String.Empty;

    SqlParameter paramater = new SqlParameter();
    paramater.ParameterName = "@SomeParameter";
    paramater.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    paramater.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    paramater.Size = 50;  

    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "SomeStoredProcedure";
                command.Parameters.Add(paramater);

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (command.Parameters["@SomeParameter"] != null)
                {
                    someValue= Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@SomeParameter"].Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SqlException)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return someValue;
}
```

1. Can it be tested using shims and/or stubs so that the output value can be set to a specific value?
2. If so how?
3. Should I even use unit testing for this?

I have followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) and managed to understand and adapt it to the day of the week.

I'm waiting on the VS2012 database unit tests functionality to become available by end of 2012 (or reinstated) as a MS employee [has commented](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3022904-continue-support-for-database-unit-tests-in-vs-201) so that the database can be tested in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Fakes is not an appropriate tool to test this code. Create an integration test instead. In this test, use a local instance of the SQL server, explicitly create data that the stored procedure expects to find in the database, call the stored procedure and verify its result. Rollback transaction or manually delete data from the database to ensure that it does not affect other tests.

Comment: Why not? By Shimming `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` you could test quite a bit of this method and its error handling without the need to access the database.

Comment: Probably want to shim the `connection.Open()` as well. It's not going to make this method easily testable or anything, but it's a way to a start.

Comment: There is very little logic in the method itself. It's mostly plumbing around the stored procedure. Could you test it with Shims? Yes. Would the tests be valuable? In my opinion, no. I would either unit test the stored procedure directly, or integration test the wrapper method as a surrogate.

Comment: I suspect that the `GetSomeDatabaseValue` isn't the actual method :). If there indeed is very little logic, then I wouldn't spend too much time on it testing it. I suspect there is more to it. At least you could check that connections are properly closed, objects were properly disposed etc. Unless you already run a static analysis tool that does that for you.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. This is just your opinion, and should be deleted.