# Trying to create an interface for unit testing that implements IDbCommand

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I'm using the VS2012 built-in Fakes framework.

This design question is related to the following post: [Unit test won't "cover" simple get method. (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260706/unit-test-wont-cover-simple-get-method-c)

I'm not certain how to design class for "IDbAccess" to successfully "fake" hitting the database.

Ex code (taken from previous post):

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    IDbAccess db;

    public Foo(IDbAccess db)
    {
        this.db = db; 
    }

    public Dictionary<string,string> GetSomething(string xyz)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string,string>
        db.commandText = "text..."
        db.connection = conn;
        result.Add(db.MethodWhatever(xyz));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Ex Test Method:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetSomething()
{
    var dba = new StubIDbAccess();
    var target = new Foo(dba);

    var expected = new Dictionary<string, string> 
    {
        {"blahKey","blahValue"}
    };

    // get something
    var results = target.GetSomething("xyzstring");

    // verify results
    var actual = results.whatever;

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected,actual);
}
```

In order to "stub" IDbAccess, IDbAccess needs to be a class that inherits from IDbCommand.  I'm just not sure how to implement it to avoid having to override everything in IDbCommand.

```
public interface IDbAccess : IDbCommand
{
    ...?
}
```

Comment: I should also mention that I need to be using an "OracleCommand" object versus an IDbCommand, which further complicates things.  The OracleCommand object doesn't have an Interface.

Comment: Found a related article.  Perhaps testing this method isn't feasible with the Fakes framework... or at least removing the db dependency.  Shiming the OracleDataAccess object, for all the trouble its going to take, might not be worth it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419883/microsoft-fakes-shims-and-or-stubs-on-a-c-sharp-method-with-sql-code

Comment: It's very unlikely that you need to fake everything involved. If you have an interface handling db access (preferably a custom wrapper), you can make a separate implementation that just returns some values you pass in. That's what Fakes is for. How the db works shouldn't matter to your method, only the returns of your specific calls.